# Typescript conditional void parameter type

Tags: typescript, types

I was trying to implement a custom Error class, which would accept different kinds of data depending on the error code. I was pretty sure that was I wanted to do was too complex for typescript to infer, but, to my surprise, this worked:

```js
const enum ERROR_CODES {
  E_AUTHORIZATION = 'Authorization error',
  E_REQUEST = 'Request failed',
  E_INVALID = 'Invalid data',
}
interface ERROR_TYPES {
  [ERROR_CODES.E_AUTHORIZATION]: string
  [ERROR_CODES.E_REQUEST]: { url: string; status: number }
  [ERROR_CODES.E_INVALID]: { action: string; field: string }
}

class MyError<TError extends ERROR_CODES> extends Error {
  constructor(
    public readonly code: TError,
    public readonly data: ERROR_TYPES[TError],
  ) { super(code) }
}
```

Now I can use it like this:

```js
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_AUTHORIZATION, 'whatever')
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_AUTHORIZATION, { 
  operation: 'login',
  field: 'email',
})
```

This works fine. Another thing I wanted to do is to create such error codes that need no data. Since it is possible to define functions like this:

```js
function foo(bar: void) {}
foo()
```

My next logical step was to write this:

```js
const enum ERROR_CODES {
  // ...
  E_UNKNOWN = 'Unknown error'
}
interface ERROR_TYPES {
  // ...
  [ERROR_CODES.E_UNKNOWN]: void
}
```

Now typescript behaves in quite a strange way. If I write this:

```js
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_UNKNOWN, undefined)
```

it works. If I write this:

```js
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_UNKNOWN)
```

it says `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`. If I write something like this:

```js
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_UNKNOWN, void 0)
```

which should basically be the same as the first example, then it says `Expected 'undefined' and instead saw 'void'.`. What is happening here and is it possible to make the second example work with just one argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce "expected `undefined` but instead saw `void`".

---

Here's how I might approach what you're trying to do.  To "optionally make a function parameter optional", I'd represent the parameter list as as [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  Consider this type alias:

```
type UndefParamToOptional<T> = undefined extends T ? [T?] : [T];
```

The type `UndefParamToOptional<string>` is just `[string]`, but `UndeParamToOptional<string | undefined>` is `[string?]`.  That's a tuple with a single [optional element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) corresponding to an optional function parameter.  Then we can implement `MyError` like this:

```
class MyError<TError extends ERROR_CODES> extends Error {
  constructor(
    code: TError,
    ...[data]: UndefParamToOptional<ERROR_TYPES[TError]>
  );
  constructor(public readonly code: TError, public readonly data: ERROR_TYPES[TError]) {
    super(code);
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

I'm using a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) signature to show how you intend to call it, while leaving the implementation signature unchanged.

Now this should behave as you expect:

```
throw new MyError(ERROR_CODES.E_UNKNOWN); // okay
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgUQEoYPIYPoDC2AImgMowDeAsAFAzp4CCAqgCoASuAkgFpNtu2AHIwAvDADkTRFAAWIAE4BLAF4BDKMvDxFipZIA0dBmjwY0ARRbk24qRjgBHRHGgwAZuuUAbOABMjE0ZuYQA1JgAZbmJ7SW4wADd1H2V-GH9NdSD6RhZhAGlhbAB1UQlJFjAAazAQAHcwSToAXzplMCg4RS9gOHQsXDw2AE0ABXIqYIBtTBx8IlIyADozVk4efkERAF0ALhhoFTAAcxgZuaHF8lXzKxsyNn2qGERFHwOjjpOAbkOoTSICAHJDIABG3RgbVys0GCxINzMoQi0WIz0oMHUwC04E+UGOv08yjgPn8eIJUIucMICJWZnyRVKwmeiDA-jgHg6AVadDoUAAngAHfpVdkeMbqRTqZBsEDYQU4sApAA8bAAfPZWWKuek4AAPLpsiAwOwAfhg0zYpp2MAOlp2P15tGAPnUEGNAFl+Wg9EpVT79Ip4AaEP5jZd4UsNfrDWH0L6gzRcqBIPjENilAAKYIMUDsg5sANKYy5BjLcvTTIA56ijkSqUyuUK7RKnzKiPDcbkS1FxQ7NXBACUjuT4CO6agWcFiDBqWAMEUcHU-nAPn5MDzcALvcMMGns+U88Xy9X66r6gOHdGEzIPYTO0HU1Lh0QwsUmc3w5zMHkyggy3PexzxHBhoWhdoPBgTMPU0ORlilNkQGQTNB0fJMGHkfR6hgMA4Gwr1e0zDtrjpZh2C4DA+AEIRhF3AAiOjBx5WhlEg6DYPg9REOQ1CnwwuQsJwvCYAIhMiOpEjbgZYoyiY2hwNoIA)

Comment: Wouh, that's cool! I've also realized that I misunderstood a bit how overloads worked. 
Speaking about the `expected 'undefined' but saw 'void'` error, this message was shown in vscode. No idea, why this happens, since I use same version as TS playground and I don't think they implemented their own compiler. Anyway, that's not so important, thanks!